# SageMaker cannot create first user

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I need to create first user to getting start, but Amazon won't let me.

> ResourceLimitExceeded The account-level service limit 'Maximum number
> of user profiles per domain' is 0 UserProfiles, with current
> utilization of 0 UserProfiles and a request delta of 1 UserProfiles.
> Please contact AWS support to request an increase for this limit.

I cannot get pass the quickstart guide.

[image]

How should I fix ? What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this same issue. To resolve you just need to request a limit increase via https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase

- **Limit type**: SageMaker Studio
- **Limit**: Max User Profiles Per Account
- **New Limit**: 1 (or more)